# Extract values from tuple inside an object instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

I have the following code that doesn't work:

```
def call_row(body_part):
    row = self.__call__()[body_part].loc[str(row_index)].tolist()
    return row[0], row[1]

vector_centre = Vector2D(x, y = call_row(body_part_centre))
```

I know I can solve the issue by changing it to something like this:

```
def call_row(body_part):
    row = self.__call__()[body_part].loc[str(row_index)].tolist()
    return row[0], row[1]

x, y = call_row(body_part_centre)
vector_centre = Vector2D(x, y)
```

Yes, Vector2D is a custom class defined by myself.

I don't find this solution that elegant. Is this the most "zen of python" style as it gets or can we make this better? I want to follow PEP8.

The most explicit version of my question would be:
Is there a way to extract values from a tuple inside an object instantiation without sacrificing elegance?

Comment: did you mean to make `call_row` a member function? then it should be `def call_row(self, body_part)`? or how does that function access `self`? ...and PEP8 is only about formatting your source code; not about how to implement anything.

Comment: What do you mean formatting source code? Isn't that the same thing as implementing it? Anyway, there is a propasal on how to format your code in PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: agreed, there are some programming recommendations as well. and no: implementing can be done equivalently in different ways (as some whitespace does not count). PEP8 is strict about that (e.g. `a = 3` vs `a=3`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unpack operator instead:

```
vector_centre = Vector2D(*call_row(body_part_centre))
```